# Matlab addpath, genpath does not work in Mac?

Tags: matlab

I have a folder named `'/Users/me/myfolder'`, which contains many subfolders. Each of these subfolders have .m or data files, whose names are unique. I did `addpath(genpath(userpath))`, and did `load('../data/filename')` and `load('filename')`, but I got errors: `No such file or directory`. How can I execute a file or load a file using `load('../data/filename')` or `load('filename')` regardless of which subfolder I am in?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little ambiguous.

1. `userpath` does not neccesarly point to `/Users/me/myfolder`

The `userpath` is "the first folder or folders in the list of folders returned by PATHDEF and thus affects the search path"

2. is '../data/filename' located in one of the subdirectories of `/Users/me/myfolder`?

If not, then it will not be on the search path and you can not load it because Matlab does not know where that file is!

---

To correctly add `/Users/me/myfolder` and all its subfolders, perform the following:

`addpath(genpath('/Users/me/myfolder'))`

Then ensure that `filename` is on that search path, if not do the same thing and add the path to `filename` to your search path using `addpath()`

Answer (score 0):

In my case `userpath` returns:

```
/Users/my_user/Documents/MATLAB:
```

But `genpath('/Users/my_user/Documents/MATLAB:')` returns an empty string. The problem is that you need to remove the colon, so, a possible solution maybe is:

```
tmp = userpath
addpath(genpath(tmp(1,end-1)))
```